# Sublime text 3 - Anaconda plugin. Not working '(' symbol?

Tags: keyboard, sublime-text-3

I don't get it why, but if I install Anaconda plugin (for Python development), then I can't use '`(`' symbol. I mean, when I try to `shift + 9`, to write `(`, nothing happens. Its like such keyboard combination is disabled (or should do something else maybe?). And of course I mean when writing it in sublime text editor.

Also I do not see such keyboard combination in Anaconda default combinations or user ones.

P.S. If I disable Anaconda plugin, then I can again write `(` normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. It seems like the Anaconda and Jedi plugins for Sublime conflict somehow; try disabling Jedi if you have it and restarting Sublime.